# "Error: receiving on an empty and disconnected channel" from `solana_client::PubsubClient`

Tags: rust, rpc, jsonrpc-api, subscription, solana-client

Consider this simple bit of code:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use solana_client::pubsub_client::PubsubClient;

const WS_URL: &str = "wss://api.devnet.solana.com";

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let (_, receiver) = PubsubClient::program_subscribe(WS_URL, &spl_token_2022::ID, None)?;
    loop {
        receiver.recv()?;
    }
}
```

I will very often get the following error with no responses:

```
Error: receiving on an empty and disconnected channel
```

Once every (approx.) 15 - 20 tries it spits out some results and then gives the same error message as above. It never runs for more than 30 seconds or so.

So the way I see it there are a few possibilities:

- I am doing it wrong
- The RPC providers are unreliable
- The RPC providers are rate limiting me in some way
- the Solana client has issues

I have tried 3 different providers (alchemy, genesysgo, and the "main" one: `api.devnet.solana.com`)

Does anyone have any advice about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I had a hunch that the async version would work... and well... it did...

I am no rust expert but it still seems that the "blocking" version of the `pubsub_client` is just straight up broken. However, if you use the async version which uses futures, it runs without issue:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use futures::prelude::*;
use solana_client::{
    nonblocking::pubsub_client::PubsubClient,
    rpc_config::{RpcTransactionLogsConfig, RpcTransactionLogsFilter},
};
use solana_sdk::commitment_config::CommitmentConfig;

const WS_URL: &str = "wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let client = PubsubClient::new(WS_URL).await?;
    let (mut stream, _) = client
        .logs_subscribe(
            RpcTransactionLogsFilter::All,
            RpcTransactionLogsConfig {
                commitment: Some(CommitmentConfig::processed()),
            },
        )
        .await?;

    loop {
        let logs = stream.next().await.unwrap();
        println!("logs: {:?}", logs);
    }
}
```

If anyone has a better answer than this, I am happy to hear it. If I don't get any feedback in a few days, I will select my own answer.